# (Cpanel Centos 7.2) Prevent external domain to access my domain just by pointing ip address

Tags: apache, cpanel, whm

I have a user account with dedicated ip address on cPanel (WHM) and a website e.g. www.domain1.com is running on that. If i use same ip address to point some external domain www.domain2.com to that account ip without adding it as addon domain, it serves the website present on that ip (www.domain1.com) on www.domain2.com. How can I restrict that if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really 'prevent' it - for example, I could buy a domain name and point it at your website.

However, what you can do is add a 'redirect' to your site. So, if the domain used to access your site is not your domain, then redirect the client to your domain name

I don't really know cPanel, but this appears to be what you want

https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Redirects